# in python regular expression,why can't (h)* and (h)+ yield same result?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I  am learning the `re` module in python. I have found something that doean't make sense(to me) and i don't know why. Here is a small example,

```
x=re.compile(r'(ha)*')
c=x.search('the man know how to hahahaha')
print(c.group())#output will be nothing,no error.But i expect "hahahaha"
```

same happens if i use `re.compile(r'(ha)?')`,

```
x=re.compile(r'(ha)?')
c=x.search('the man know how to hahahaha')
print(c.group())#output will be nothing,no error.But i expect "ha".
```

But if i use `re.compile(r'(ha)+')`,

```
x=re.compile(r'(ha)+')
c=x.search('the man know how to hahahaha')
print(c.group())#output will be `hahahaha`,just as expected.
```

Why is this,aren't `re.compile(r'(ha)*')` and `re.compile(r'(ha)+')` same in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `r'h+'` and `r'h*'` are not identical, thats why they do not deliver the same result. `+` implies 1 or more matches of your pattern, `*` zero or more:

`re.search` returns "nothing" because it only looks at the **first** match. The *first* match for `*` is a zero occurence of your `'(ha)'` pattern at the first letter of your string:

```
import re
x=re.compile(r'(ha)*')
c=x.findall('the man know how to hahahaha')   # get _all_ matches
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ha', '']

# t   h  e        m   a   n       k   n   o   w      h    o   w       t   o      hahahaha
```

`*` and `?` quantifier allow 0 matches

Doku:

> **Pattern.search(string[, pos[, endpos]])**
>   Scan through string looking for the **first** location where this regular expression produces a match, ...
>   (source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search)

Comment: Thank you for you answer,but  if there are three "ha" in the last,why does it throw only one "ha"?

Comment: @Tom  `(ha)*` matches 0 to n ha's - so the full match is `hahahaha` but you capture only one of them inside your grouping-parenthesis: your grouping only contains one `'(ha)'`. - change the pattern to `r'((?:ha)*)'` if you want all `ha` that are matched. When new to regex- use http://regex101.com  and set the mode to python to experiment. It will even explain your patterns to you.